# How can select user with category and with rate number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

[image]
I want to select all users with category and sum of the rate users.
please help me

Comment: You need select all users where category is not null or create a group by  with user-category and sum this rating?

Comment: Very cryptic question.  Please provide a starting SQL query, clarify your question or sample output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test this queries.. you need read about *left join* and *group by*.

User SUM(rate) *(where category is not null)*

```
SELECT r.user_id, SUM(r.rate_number) FROM rate AS r LEFT JOIN user AS u ON r.user_id = u.id WHERE u.category_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY r.user_id
```

User Category SUM(rate)

```
SELECT r.user_id, u.category_id, SUM(r.rate_number) FROM rate AS r LEFT JOIN user AS u ON r.user_id = u.id WHERE u.category_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY r.user_id, u.category_id
```

Comment: In this example i use id columns... if you need more info add to the query the columns or utilize other left join to category to get more information.